# I want to fetch user id from wp_user table. I wrote following code but it is not working

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I want the code which creates user if it is not present in db and it is working fine but if user is authentic then I want to give access to wordpress site.Control is going in Else block but I am not able to fetch ID of user from email with following code which written in else block. What should I do to achieve that?

```
if($bearer_token){

    global $wpdb;
    $name = $_POST['log'];
    $email = $_POST['log'];

    //$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpuser";

    include_once(ABSPATH . '/var/www/html/wp-config.php');
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $link = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);
    if($link){
    //  echo "Success";
        ////////////////

        $db_name = $wpdb->prefix . "users";
       // echo $table_name;
        $wpdb->insert( $db_name, array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email
        ) );

        ///////////////
    }else{
        echo "Fail";
    }

}else{
    echo "Error";
}

//////////////////////////

if($bearer_token){
add_action( 'init', function () {

  $username = $_POST['log'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];
  $email_address = $_POST['log'];
  //$url = "0.0.0.0:8000"
//    echo "if inside";



  if ( ! username_exists( $username ) ) 

    {    
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email_address );
    echo $user_id;
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user->set_role( 'contributor' );

    }elseif (username_exists($username)==True) {
        // $user = get_user_by( 'user_email', $email_address );
        // $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userdata = WP_User::get_data_by( 'user_login', $username );

    if ( !$userdata )
        return false;

    $user = new WP_User;
    $user->init( $userdata );

    return $user;

        # code...
    }else{
        echo "Errorrr";
    }
    }
   );
}else{
    echo "Unauthenticate user";
}
```

Comment: Where is variable  $email_address set?  and why would you not use the $username which you have just verified exists? eg: 


get_user_by('user_login', $username);


Also note possible case sensitivities:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/#comment-2493

Comment: When control goes to else block then I want user to go on wordpress site  for access. What code I have to add to tha in else blockt?

Comment: Generally one would redirect to the login screen so that the user could enter their password, but I suspect you have something else going on here.   (Auto creating users at contributor level sounds dangerous for example - you could   end up with alot of garbage.   Where is this code executing ? Where does username get entered from?     Alternatively these old posts may help https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53503/can-i-programmatically-login-a-user-without-a-password

Comment: I am authenticating user from one api and I am getting credentials from that api and when user is authenticated I want to store those credentials in wordpress user table. I am successful in creation of user in wordpress and store it in wp_user table but when user login again with same username but different password then I want to update his password in wordpress db with the password I got from api and  I want to give him access to wordpress site.I am updating my code above.Please have a look on it and suggest changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you have decided on how you will differentiate between first login by a user and all the subsequent logins by the same user. But if you want to create a new user every time you encounter a new email, the simplest way would be to pass your login credential to `wp_authenticate($username, $password)` and you can override this to perform custom check as follow:

```
add_action( 'wp_authenticate' , 'check_custom_authentication', 10, 2 );

function check_custom_authentication ( $username, $password ) {
        if ( ! username_exists( $username ) ) {
            return;
        }
        // use wp_set_password function here to set password by getting user id from the login detail we have.
}
```